# Which ASP.NET server control should I use?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I am looking for a simple lightweight ASP.NET server control to render 2 columns, a label and a radio button list. It literally should look like this.

```
Gender        Male/Female
Recommend us  Yes/No
and so on..
```

I feel that a repeater or a datagrid is an overkill as this page needs to be high performant page and should be very light.

What server control do you recommend?

Comment: Can this list change based upon the database (or other config) or is it hardcoded?

Comment: List cannot be hardcoded. Its based on the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please define high performance and "very light".  If by "very light" you mean the rendered HTML markup, the Repeater control is the best choice because you control the markup completely.  If you mean server-side processing, you probably want to write a custom control.

However, the gains over the repeater on the server-side would be negligible after the initial load if you can use output caching.

---

I tested a pure HTML solution vs a repeater solution with your example of two rows.
**Control (blank page):** 693 bytes rendered to client, .22 msec
**Pure HTML solution:** 1,029 bytes rendered to client, Server Processing time: .26 msec
**Repeater solution:** 2,196 bytes rendered to client, Server Processing time: .47 msec *(the majority of the overhead is due to using a radiobuttonlist control)*

You're talking about 1 kb uncompressed and .21 milliseconds overhead for using the repeater and radiobuttonlist.

In exchange, you get to maintain this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <asp:Repeater ID="r" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Literal ID="l" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" Text='<%# Eval("Label") %>' />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbl" runat="server" EnableViewState="false" 
                        DataSource='<%# ((Option)Container.DataItem).RadioButtonLabels %>'
                            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow">
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

instead of this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("<table><tbody>");

foreach (Option option in options)
{
    sb.AppendFormat("<tr><td>{0}</td><td>", option.Label);

    foreach (string label in option.RadioButtonLabels)
    {
        sb.AppendFormat("{0}<input type=\"radio\" name=\"{1}\" value=\"{0}\" />", label, option.Label);
    }

    sb.Append("</td></tr>");
}

sb.Append("</tbody></table>");
```

Personally I prefer the 1st option, but you may prefer the second.

Comment: I have 15-20 of these on this page which adds up pretty quickly. Although I am leaning towards the first option as well, I would like to know if there's a way to reduce the size and the processing time. I see that you haven't switched off viewstate at the repeater level. Any reason for that?

Comment: No, not really.  Just an oversight.  if you switch off viewstate, you'll have to bind every Page_Init, just so you know.  I think you can see a reasonable gain if you avoid the RadioButtonList which renders some pretty large markup.  The Repeater itself is lean.

Comment: I spent like 30 minutes writing this up and testing it and a 4-word answer gets more votes then mine. :sad:

Comment: I am accepting your answer as that's what I ended up doing. Using the repeater was less complex and more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel that a repeater or a datagrid
>   is an overkill as this page needs to
>   be high performant page and should be
>   very light.

i suggest pure html.

Comment: I need the radiobutton to be a server control

Comment: you can do what you want through html&javascript.<table><tbody><tr><td>Gender</td><td>Male<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Femal<input type="radio" name="gender" value="femal" /></td></tr></tbody>...and you can get the user's selection like this Request.Form["gender"]

Answer (score 1):

Smells like micro-optimization to me.  Putting a repeater or datagrid on your page, for what you've specified above, will cause absolutely no delay in your page -- it's unnecessary, but it won't cause an issue.  That is unless you're serving your site off a 2400 baud modem, which I doubt you are.

You haven't specified whether this control will be reused on multiple pages.  If it won't be, you're just adding unnecessary complexity to your application by making it a web control.  If all you're planning on doing is display static content like you have above, just keep it simple and display the fields just as you've displayed them above -- in a two column table, with a label in one, and radio buttons in the other.

If you are planning on reusing the control, my vote is to still add the controls as you would normally add a control -- without the use of a repeater or datagrid.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as a Web User Control would work out best for you as you will be able to keep the "over head" to a minimum.

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

I like the `ListView` for its flexibility.